# Deserializing a char* into a struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, strtok

I've the following struct

```
typedef struct PATH{
    int server1;
    int server2;
    int weight;
}PATH;
```

These are stored in an array.

I'm using the following function to serialize the array into a string.

```
char* serialize(PATH** arr, int sz){

    char* buffer = calloc(50, sz * 64);
    buffer[0] = 0;

    char str[64];

    for (int i = 0; i < sz ; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(str, "\n%d %d %d\n", arr[i]->server1, arr[i]->server2, arr[i]->weight);
        strcat(buffer, str);
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Till here, the code works fine.

Now I'm using the following function to deserialize the string back into the struct and write it back to an array.

```
void deserialize(PATH** arr, char* msg){
    int idx = 0;
    char* c = strtok(msg, " ");
    while(c != NULL){
        PATH path;
        path.server1 = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
        path.server2 = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
        path.weight = atoi(strtok(NULL,"\n"));
        memcpy(arr[idx], &path, sizeof(path));
        idx++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < idx; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", arr[i]->server1, arr[i]->server2, arr[i]->weight);
    }
    //do nothing for now
}
```

This function call throws up a `segmentation fault`
What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Use a gdb first. remember, using strtok on string literals are fatal.

Comment: Your code uses a `PATH` struct, but you've shown the definition for the (seemingly-unused) `SERVER` struct.

Comment: Apologies, fixed it now.

Comment: Also: what would ever cause `c` to be `NULL`? It's never set in the loop.

Comment: You're calling `strtok` thrice in your `while` loop without checking its return value; chances are one of these calls reaches the end of the string and returns NULL, you then pass this to `atoi`, invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: OT: This line `buffer[0] = 0;` is redundant as the `calloc()` already `0`ed out where `buffer` is pointing to.

Comment: You might like to have a looks at `sscanf()`.

Comment: @szczurcio wouldn't c become null, when the loop reaches the end of the char*

Comment: why don't you directly dump your structure into a char[] ?

Comment: How is `deserialize()` called and how are the variables passed in declared?

Comment: @Antithesis, no, if `c` is not set `NULL` by the initial call to `strtok()` then it will never become `NULL` because you never assign any other value to it.  This is very likely your main problem.

Comment: @alk the PATH** arr has been malloced in main, so if msg.

Answer (score -3):

```
char* c = strtok(msg, " ");
```

There should be `"\n"` here.

edit: and probably you have not reserved memory for `arr`, but we can't see that.

Comment: No, in fact the `strtok()` is not a problem as it is.  Also, although not having space allocated for `arr` would be a problem, the OP's code will fail even if space is allocated.